# How to read only one value from Firebase Database in Android Studio?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my database in Firebase Database:

[image: This is my database in Firebase:]

How can I read the value of only `a1` from my Firebase Database in my Android app and store it in a String variable `ra1`? Example Java code using the given database would be really helpful.

Thank You.

Comment: morpion_c76af is one of the childs right? if so whats the name of its parent. or is this the whole databse?

Comment: morpion_c76af  is the parent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, you just want to retrieve that String **ONCE**, and **not listen for any changes**.

So, what you do:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener(){

  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
     String value = dataSnapshot.child("a1").getValue(String.class); //This is a1
   }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Initiliaze root and add childeventlistener:

```
DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("morpion_c76af");
    root.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            if(dataSnapshot.getKey().equals("a1")) {
                String a = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue()
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: But he wants to get the data once and not listen to any events.

Comment: @jerin you forgot to inform them how to remove the reference. Which is important else you could have an app that has thousands of realtime listeners and "eating" data.